# Trying to create a view with an inline view joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, view, google-bigquery, inline

I am currently trying to create a view on google BigQuery but I keep getting the error of:

> Failed to save view. Ambiguous field name 'alias' in JOIN. Please use the table qualifier before field name.

I am trying to create a view where the user is able to see for each player_id a total of the converted_deposit_amount for each specfied value of the calculated month_difference.

I have joined 3 tables within the inline view, I can run the query just fine but I am getting the error, is there any reason to as why and how can I resolve this?

```
select
player_id,
round(sum(if(month_difference_M = 1, converted_deposit_amount, 0)),2) as M1_real_deposit_gbp,
round(sum(if(month_difference_M = 2, converted_deposit_amount, 0)),2) as M2_real_deposit_gbp,
round(sum(if(month_difference_M = 3, converted_deposit_amount, 0)),2) as M3_real_deposit_gbp,
round(sum(if(month_difference_M > 2, converted_deposit_amount, 0)),2) as M2_plus_deposit_gbp
FROM
(
  select
  pl.player_id as player_id,
  (12 * YEAR(pf.date) + MONTH(pf.date)) - (12 * YEAR(pl.ftd_date) + MONTH(pl.ftd_date)) + IF (DAY(pf.date) >= DAY(pl.ftd_date), 0, -1) + 1 as month_difference_M,
  (case
  when pf.currency = 'CAD' then pf.deposit_real_funds_amount*er.cad
  when pf.currency = 'NZD' then pf.deposit_real_funds_amount*er.nzd
  when pf.currency = 'EUR' then pf.deposit_real_funds_amount*er.eur
  when pf.currency = 'AUD' then pf.deposit_real_funds_amount*er.aud
  when pf.currency = 'NOK' then pf.deposit_real_funds_amount*er.nok
  when pf.currency = 'SEK' then pf.deposit_real_funds_amount*er.sek
  when pf.currency = 'USD' then pf.deposit_real_funds_amount*er.usd
  else pf.deposit_real_funds_amount
  end) as converted_deposit_amount
  from [enigma-1180:Tableau.PlayerFinancials] pf
  join [enigma-1180:Tableau.PlayerLookup] pl
  on pl.player_id = pf.player_id
  join [enigma-1180:Tableau.ExchangeRates] er
  on er.date = pf.date
) src
group by player_id
```

Comment: I don't know the intricacies of Bigquery, but this query looks to me to be valid on most databases.  Are you sure this is the actual code which caused the error?

Comment: Hi Tim,yes I am sure that there is something in the code that is causing the error since I am not able to create a view from this

Comment: Please use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead. It doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Hi Elliott, I am now resorting to that since I have made a few test views but just found out that Tableau does not support legacy SQL